# Why did joining a site create a generic user name for me?

Tags: bug, user-accounts

A question on EL&U interested me, so I clicked on the "Join this community" button and created an answer.

The odd thing was that it created a new generic username for me, although the linked network profile is my own one, and there's a list of my other communities there.

Is this a bug, or intentional, or did I inadvertently press the wrong button?

[image]

Comment: That's odd. I have an account basically everywhere on the SE network and this has never happened to me.

Comment: @Luuklag I can see [his account there with the generic username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSlgr.png) from his network profile.

Comment: this happened to me once as well. Is some weird race condition.

Comment: @Mast it doesn't show up here: https://stackexchange.com/users/6623302/snow?tab=accounts

Comment: @Luuklag umm, there's a reason why you can't see the account but mods can see it (hint: the "Hidden communities" on the screenshot) :)

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. You're onto something there. "did I inadvertently press the wrong button?" Not necessarily, but you may have hidden more communities than you intended to. It's possible that if you have 1+ hidden community, all new accounts are 'hidden' as well. I could definitely understand the logic behind that side effect. I have no hidden communities on my account, so that would explain why I never ran into it as well.