# Why does joining a new community result in a random gravatar & screen name?

Tags: discussion, bug, profile-page

I joined a couple of sites today (through the "Join this Community" button) and was surprised to see a completely random new user profile created.

[image]

However, I gained the 100 bonus for each site because I'm "trusted".

It's easy enough to fix the gravatar and screen name, but this seems like a bug to me.

Example - https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/128199/user128199?tab=profile

This has happened before with my profile, but from comments this seemed to be regarded as a "one-off".  It doesn't seem to be the case.

Related - [Why did joining a site create a generic user name for me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364435/why-did-joining-a-site-create-a-generic-user-name-for-me)

Comment: Hmmm you have all the normal user history events *except* for an event that your profile was copied from another site. It's like the system just didn't even try, which is certainly weird. I have a hunch that it is related to an Augur profile that is still mapped to your account despite closing years ago. For some reason, that site database still exists. It might be seeing that as your oldest profile, trying to access it, and getting blocked because the site is closed. I wonder if this happens to all users whose oldest linked profile is to a closed site.

Comment: @animuson would this have anything to do with the fact that I scheduled the deletion of all my accounts when I left the SE network at the end of 2019?

Comment: The scheduling itself, no. The profile was scheduled for deletion but was never formally deleted because the site is closed.  There is some very odd logic where certain pieces of code can't see closed sites while other pieces can... But all your other profiles disappearing would be a quick way to make it the oldest. I tried manually deleting the profile and it seems to have worked. Would you wanna try creating another profile and see what happens?

Comment: @animuson Yes, that worked!  I just joined two new communities and got the expect profile created.  Thanks so much for getting this sorted out!

Comment: Possibly related: *[Profile image changes (Gravatar images won’t be recoverable after email change)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370187)*